# Know of any JQuery slider that also magnifys the current slide?

Tags: jquery, slider, magnification

I'm looking to create a similar effect to the one used in the header bar for this page:

http://www.sjlwebdesign.co.uk/portfolio/

Any idea's on a plugin or method that would achieve this effect easily?

**Edit:** When i say similar, I would like to have an area in the center of a header panel that actually magnifys the image as it slides into the center. Unlike the above example which simply cuts it.

Thanks,
Jai

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're not doing anything special with jQuery really, just using the [easySlider plugin](http://cssglobe.com/post/4004/easy-slider-15-the-easiest-jquery-plugin-for-sliding) along with a [clever background image](http://www.sjlwebdesign.co.uk/img/portfolio/carousel-top.png) to mask the 'inactive' slides.

Comment: nice spot, but i've realised i missed a vital part out of my question.

Answer (score 2):

[Roundabout](http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/) is a jQuery carousel that is very dynamic.